# List of aggregates inside an aggregate

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, microservices, ef-core-2.0

I am modeling the Student and Attendance functionality using DDD aggregates. What I ended up was Student class having a list of Attendance records. I am using EF core to load the student along with all the attendances associated to the student.

So every day there will a attendance record registered against a student. The attendance record can be updated multiple times through out the day. I ended up creating a public method on the Student class called CreateOrUpdateAttendance(Date date, AttendanceDetails attendance) which would internally check if there are any attendance record for the given date if not create a new attendance instance, update this attendance record with the provided attendance details add/ update list of attendance associated to the student. So every time there is a attendance updated/ created for a student the student entity is queried from the data base along with all attendance records. Student is queried based on the Id received from input to check whether the provided Id is valid or not.

The problem is as days go by there would be many attendance records associated to the student which means unnecessary pulling of all attendance records associated to the student which will lead to poor query performance.

Is Student the proper root here? Unfortunately EF core doesn't support filtering child objects yet.

My question is how to deal the use case where the child entities needs to be updated inside an aggregate More specifically a single entity of the list of entities inside an aggregate?

In this case should I treat the Attendance as different aggregate? So that I can query the attendance record independent of the student record?

I ended up making two calls to database one to check the student(with out loading the attendance) and other to fetch the attendance record.

I am missing something here? Should I rethink my design? Any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Student the proper root here?

An Aggregate is a consistency boundary. It exists to ensure that the entities contained therein are in a consistent, (i.e. valid) state as it pertains to your business rules. You haven't yet described any business rules or validations that should be ensured so I don't know that Student is the correct Aggregate. Read on...

> Unfortunately EF core doesn't support filtering child objects yet.

EF Core does not support filtering child collections, but there might be other ways to accomplish this. Here is some pseuodcode:

```
var query = 
    from s in ctx.Students
    where s.Id == 1 // Student filter here
    select new 
    {
        Student = s,
        Student = 
            from sa in s.StudentAttendances
            where sa. // Apply filter here
            select sa
    };

// Perform the query against the DB and then return the Student object
// EF will wire up the relationships for you and because you went to the
// DB first before pulling the student, the data is local and you will
// have the full tree
var student = query.ToList().Select(x => x.Student).FirstOrDefault();
```

> In this case should I treat the Attendance as different aggregate? So that I can query the attendance record independent of the student record?

It depends on your business rules. What are the lifetimes of the Student and Attendance? Can the Student have any number of Attendances? Think more about your Write Use Cases and less about your Read Use Cases. Do you need to load StudentAttendances at all? Is that simply a Read Use Case?

Also consider whether ONE Student Aggregate is sufficient. Should you load all of the Attendance records when you simply want to change a phone number? Just as we have Bounded Contexts, you might consider having Bounded Aggregates, e.g. vertical partitions of an Aggregate within a Bounded Context splitting what sounds like one single, large concept into several smaller concepts.

You can have:

- A Student Aggregate with a filtered list of Attendances (as illustrated above)
- A StudentAttendance Aggregate (as you mentioned)
- A StudentWithAttendance Aggregate which is separate from the Student Aggregate and serves a different use case

> I am missing something here? Should I rethink my design?

It depends. Generally, I would suggest thinking more at a Domain level and less at a DB level. Think more about Writes than Reads.

EF forces us, in some ways to think in a relational way even as we model our Domain, but we should fight that urge and relegate EF to a simple persistence mechanism where possible and not let it drive our Domain design decisions.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning various ways I can go with this problem domain. We analyzed our bounded context and identified Attendance and User as two distinct sub domains.

Attendance does have quite a few business rules/ in variants compared to User. The previous version of User was just delegating calls to the filtered attendance record. Once we identified User and Attendance as two separate aggregates the code flowed naturally.

Comment: Special Thanks for reminding me that EF is just a persistence abstraction and to focus on domain. I am new to DDD and microservices and i am slowly realizing and experiencing the benefits it provides.